# Pytorch,How to feed output of CNN into input of RNN?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to CNN, RNN and deep learning.
I am trying to make architecture that will combine CNN and RNN.
input image size = [20,3,48,48]
a CNN output size = [20,64,48,48]
and now i want cnn ouput to be RNN input
but as I know the input of RNN must be 3-dimension only which is [seq_len, batch, input_size]
How can I make 4-dimensional [20,64,48,48] tensor into 3-dimensional for RNN input?

and another question how do I initiate the first hidden state with

```
torch.zeros()
```

I don't know what exact information I should pass in this function. the only thing that I know it is

```
[layer_dim, batch, hidden_dim]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just in sake of clarity : the first dimension of your cnn tensor (20) looks like a batch size. Is that going to be the temporal dimension of your RNN, i. e. seq_len? This is something that depends on your design and on what you actually want to do.

Comment: I am not sure. I don't think 20 should be seq_len cause there are input for the batch_size which is 20

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `20` here is size of a batch. In that case, set `batch = 20`.

`seq_len` is the number of time steps in each stream. Since one image is input at one time step, `seq_len = 1`.

Now, `20` images of size `(64, 48, 48)` has to be converted for the format

Since the size of input is (64, 48, 48), `input_size = 64 * 48 * 48`

```
model = nn.LSTM(input_size=64*48*48, hidden_size=1).to(device)

#Generating input - 20 images of size (60, 48, 48)
cnn_out = torch.randn((20, 64, 48, 48)).requires_grad_(True).to(device)

#To pass it to LSTM, input must be of the from (seq_len, batch, input_size)
cnn_out = cnn_out.view(1, 20, 64*48*48)

model(cnn_out)
```

This will give you the result.

Comment: Hi, @Arun . Many thank for the answer. After I try your solution I found another problem. Some how pytorch need the first hidden state as `[1, 1, 1]` . I don't know why. And now my out out of RNN is `[1, 20, 1]` . I thought my output will be `[1, 20, 147456]` . So I can reshape my output shape back to Image input shape `[20, 64, 48, 48]`

Answer (score 0):

By following @Arun soulution. Finally I can pass image tensor though RNN Layer
But the problem after is some how pytorch need the first hidden state as [1, 1, 1] only. I don't know why. And now my output of RNN is [1, 20, 1] . 
I thought my output will be [1, 20, 147456] . So I can reshape my output shape back to Image input shape [20, 64, 48, 48]

```
class Rnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rnn, self).__init__()
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(64*48*48, 1, 1, batch_first=True, nonlinearity='relu')

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        hidden = self.init_hidden(batch_size)
        images = x.view(1, 20, 64*48*48)
        out, hidden = self.rnn(images, hidden)
        out = torch.reshape(out, (20,64,96,96))
        return out, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        hidden = torch.zeros(1, 1, 1).to(device)
        return hidden
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question is very interesting.The output of CNN is 4 dimension,but the input of RNN require 3 dimension.

Obviourly, you know the meaning of dimension. The problem is samply be shape operation.

Comment: I have a guess that if RNN input require [seq_len, batch, input_size] then my input should be [seq_len, 20, 64*48*48]. But what is seq_len? and How i get it?

Comment: I never use RNN actually.But in pytorch or keras,I seem rember the seq_len is default 1.Maybe you can try it.